# Rotate element once it is selected flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

Recently I have created a post about how to rotate a dismissible element once it is swiped.
 I did get an answer so I decided to rewrite a question.

---

For example, I have a container with gesturedetector() widget, is it possible to scale it and rotate 5 deg.(duration like 5sec.) once it is tapped or longpress?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in an [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html) which is a container that gradually changes its values over a period of time.

The duration of the transformation is controlled by specifying something like `duration: new Duration(seconds:5)` in the AnimatedContainer's constructor.

You can also specify additional transformations by for example scaling variables for the AnimatedContainer's width and height properties.

For more information, the [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/animation/animated-container) have a good intro to using AnimatedContainers.

Comment: tried animated container, but it does not work with rotation.
thanks for your time